# Are there striking or weapon styles that use hip tilt?

Tags: kung-fu, jujutsu, striking

In Shorinji Kempo we make a point of learning to use different hip positions.  I forget the exact Japanese names but basically we have hip forwards and hip backwards stances that we use in different situations.

Shorinji Kempo has an unusual herritage that is a mixture of Japanese Jujitsu and Chinese Qi Na (from Northern Shaolin style).  For this reason I don't know what the origin of this emphasis on hip position actually is.  It might even be a kenjutsu type skill.

Comment: What does it mean for a hip to be forwards or backwards? Is that changing [pitch or yaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes)?

Comment: Changing pitch.

Comment: Are you only interested in striking arts? Hip positioning is important for jiu jitsu and wrestling too.

Comment: Not really,  Hip positioning is very different in grappling.

Comment: My memory of SK is rusty after 40 years. Are you talking about chudan gamae and ichiji gamae?  (spelling?)

Comment: No these are variations on those stances. I think the Japanese names are ko sidache and zen sidache.

Comment: Is this question about why martial arts have different hip positions? Of is this about the particular origins for Shorinji Kempo? Is this difference from each other, or one system has multiple hip positions? As currently asked, any answer with a system having different hip positions seems equally good.

Comment: My intent was to ask what other striking or weapon styles used hip tilt to move forward and backward.

Comment: Can you add some images for the two versions? that would be quite useful ...

Comment: I'll try to upload a YouTube video.

Answer (score 1):

One principle applied in bagua striking is to use the spine as a whip to transmit power. The whipping motion starts as a wave in the hips; any strike using this principle works through a range of hip pitch angles. [This video](https://youtu.be/We7jTGkyD84?t=100) is a sufficient example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly iffy answer in that it's basically drawing in individual techniques from two different styles (and maybe a non-MMA movement), but boxing has the [bolo punch](https://blackbeltwiki.com/bolo-punch), which was introduced by Filipino workers who sourced the movement from a combination of their [native styles](https://stickfightingsport.com/kali/) and the machete movement used to cut sugar cane. While most people think of the circular movement of the arm as the fundamental part of it, the starting location by the hips is actually to use the hip movement to drive the cut without having to rely on arm strength.